# Configuring a DNS Server like OpenDNS

Tags: server, dns, bind

I want to configure a bind server that responds with a zone file even if this zone file was not created earlier.

Basically I need a parking DNS server that every responds to every domain name (just like OpenDNS' fallback server)

Does Bind allow a DNS server like that or do you have any other server to do this in short way?

Comment: This question is not Ubuntu-specific. In the future, Serverfault would be more appropriate for questions like this.

Comment: @Celada Lots of questions posted on our site would also be applicable to one or more other operating system. This fits fully within the scope of our site as defined in [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). This question should not be closed, and future questions like this should be welcomed.

Comment: @EliahKagan OK, I stand corrected. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I find it unintuitive though, since I would not look for information about DNS server configuration in general on a Linux-distribution-specific site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you don't need BIND to respond with a zone file (which implies the DNS zone transfer protocol) but rather you need it to answer queries for normal types (like `A`, `MX`, etc...) for any name with chosen data.

One way to do this is to configure your server to be authoritative for the root zone (".") and put wildcard records in it. This is not technically correct because the zone apex will not correspond to the delegation points, but it works in practice.

For example: in `named.conf`:

```
zone "." {
    type master;
    file "db.root";
};
```

And in the root zone file:

```
@    IN    SOA    your.server.name. your.email.address. (
                  2012093001 604800 86400 2419200 86400 )
     IN    NS     your.server.name.

*    IN    foo    bar
     IN    baz    quux
```

...where "foo bar" and "baz quux" are the RRtype and RRdata of the records you would like to serve for every name under the root.

**Note**: make sure you don't use the same server as a recursive resolver!